# Optional function parameter with generic return type

Tags: scala, types

How would you implement class that parses some input via regex and transforms founded string to some other type? My approach is:

```
class ARegex[T](regex:Regex, reform:Option[String => T]){
  def findFirst(input:String):Option[T] = {
    (regex.findFirstIn(input), reform) match{
      case (None, _) => None
      case (Some(s), None) => Some(s) // this won't compile because of type mismatch
      case (Some(s), Some(fun)) => Some(fun(s))
    }
  }
}

class BRegex[T](regex:Regex, reform:Option[String => T]) {
  def findFirst(input:String) = {  //returns Option[Any] - erasure
    (regex.findFirstIn(input), reform) match{
      case (None, _) => None
      case (Some(s), None) => Some(s)
      case (Some(s), Some(fun)) => Some(fun(s))
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `T` could be anything. The only common supertype of that `T` and `String` is `Any`. If you sometimes want to return `Some[String]` and other times `Some[T]` (or `None`), then `Option[Any]` the most you can say about the return type of `findFirst`.

Comment: For fun have a look at : http://github.com/league/scala-type-anxiety/blob/master/src/RegexMatchCPS.scala

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can solve this problem by eliminating the `Option` part of the `reform`'s type, and using a different mechanism to indicate that we don't want to change the match in any way. This mechanism is to use `identity` as a default parameter or pass identity when you don't want the type to change.

```
class ARegex[T](regex:Regex, reform:String => T = identity[String](_)){
  def findFirst(input:String):Option[T] = {
    regex.findFirstIn(input) match{
      case None => None
      case Some(s) => Some(reform(s))
    }
  }
}

new ARegex("something".r).findFirst("something else") //returns Option[String]
new ARegex("3".r, {x=>x.toInt}).findFirst("number 3") //returns Option[Int]
```

Comment: Oh, I like this! It didn't occur to me to use identity as a default parameter.

Comment: You could rewrite the body of `findFirst` to `regex findFirstIn input map reform`, though. It would really show off Scala elegance.

Comment: @Daniel, that probably is the most idiomatic way to write it. I didn't do it that way (actually, I did but reverted it... check the edit history) because I felt that it might obscure the important part of my answer if I deviated too much from the original.

Answer (score 2):

Well, the problem *is* the type mismatch, because you are returning either a `String` or a `T`, which, of course, are unified at `Any`. You can't say you are going to return `Option[T]` and then return `Option[String]`.

Other than that, a simplified version of that code is this:

```
class ARegex[T](regex: Regex, reform: Option[String => T]) {
  def findFirst(input: String): Option[Any] =
    regex findFirstIn input map { s => reform map (_(s)) getOrElse s }
}
```

You could return an `Option[Either[String, T]]`, though. The code would look like this:

```
class ARegex[T](regex: Regex, reform: Option[String => T]) {
  def findFirst(input: String): Option[Either[String, T]] =
    regex findFirstIn input map { s => reform map (_(s)) toRight s }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why is reform Option[String => T] instead of just String => T? If you don't pass in a mechanism for creating an instance of your desired type, there's no mechanism for the runtime system to actually create the appropriate object. If you really need to pass in an Option[String => T] then your second case should simply return None.

Also, flatMap is your friend, and will give you the correct behavior (i.e. if reform is None, the method returns None.

```
class RegexExtractor[T](regex: Regex, reform: Option[String => T]) {
  def findFirst(input: String): Option[T] = reform.flatMap(f => regex.findFirstIn(input).map(f))
}
```

Comment: I don't think correct behavior is for `findFirst` to return `None` if if `reform` is `None`. He's looking for a way to omit the `reform` function and have `findFirst` skip the transformation under those circumstances.