# Scala constructor with default arg referencing another arg

Tags: scala, constructor

I would to make the second constructor argument optional, and use the value of the first argument in that case. Is there any way I can do that ? This code doesn't compile as it can't find `realUser`:

```
class CurrentUser(val realUser:String, val masqueradeUser:String = realUser)
```

I'm sure I *can* work around it by writing my own constructor, but I wondered if there were a more concise way. Actually now that I've tried writing my own constructor, it isn't that bad:

```
class CurrentUser(val realUser:String, val masqueradeUser:String) {
    def this(realUser:String) = this(realUser, realUser)
}
```

If someone can come up with something shorter then great, otherwise I'll post my own answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks for the suggestions. I think I will stick with specifying the second constructor form manually. Here it is as an answer for completeness' sake.

```
class CurrentUser(val realUser:String, val masqueradeUser:String) {
    def this(realUser:String) = this(realUser, realUser)
}
```

Answer (score 11):

I believe your solution with the auxiliary constructor is the better one. A parameter is not visible in its own parameter list, only in the following ones. So you would have to do

```
class CurrentUser(val realUser: String)(val masqueradeUser: String = realUser)
```

and then call with

```
new CurrentUser(real)()
```

Not too nice.

Comment: Cool - I've never really used multiple parameter lists before. You're correct that perhaps this isn't the place to use them though :)

Answer (score 8):

You can’t reuse parameters from the same parameter list as default arguments. didierd’s solution works, and probably your solution with a second constructor is the most elegant. Here's a third alternative, which uses the dreaded `null`:

```
scala> class CurrentUser(val realUser:String, _masqueradeUser: String = null) {
     |   val masqueradeUser = if (_masqueradeUser == null) realUser else _masqueradeUser
     | }
defined class CurrentUser

scala> new CurrentUser("paul").masqueradeUser
res1: String = paul

scala> new CurrentUser("paul", "p").masqueradeUser
res2: String = p
```

If you want to avoid `null`, you can use the `Opt[A]` class [discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4199393/are-options-and-named-default-arguments-like-oil-and-water-in-a-scala-api/4200762#4200762) if you don't mind the overhead. One way or another, I’d still go with your second-constructor solution.