# Can't find inner class in scala

Tags: class, scala

Look at this example:

```
class Outer(private val handler: Actor){
  def this() = this(new Handler)  // type Handler not found ? ?

 class Handler extends Actor{
    override  def act() {

    }
  }
}
```

The compiler complain that class `Handler` is not found. Is this a bug  ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The inner class `Handler` has a reference on the outer class instance, and you're trying to create a `new Handler` before the outer instance exists — which is impossible.

You can try something like this instead:

```
class Outer(h: Actor = null) {

  private val handler =
    if (h != null) h
    else new Handler

  class Handler extends Actor {
    override def act() {

    }
  }
}
```

If you're worried about using `null`, you can use [the solution described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4199393/are-options-and-named-default-arguments-like-oil-and-water-in-a-scala-api/4200762#4200762) to replace `null` in default values for parameters.

Answer (score 2):

First of all you probably know that access to inner classes is via the dot (.) operator. So accessing the `Handler` class should be `Outer.Handler`. When you're in scope `this` the compiler cannot locate the `Handler` class, because the inner class is tied to the outer object. Everything is explained much better here: http://www.scala-lang.org/node/115. In short you get a quite impossible situation, because the inner class is hidden inside the outer class, but an actual instantiation of the outer class requires the inner class...

There are many ways to solve it I guess, I'll just quickly sketch one here. Since you probably want the `Handler` class to be tied to `Outer` in some way, I'd recommend creating and object and then calling the Outer class from here. Thus you'd get roughly the same syntax and everything is stored in one place. It could look something like this:

```
class Outer(private val handler : Actor)

object Outer {
  class Handler extends Actor { override def act { } } // The "inner" class
  def apply() = new Outer(new Handler)
  def apply(handler : Actor) = new Outer(handler)
}
```

Hope that helps :)

Comment: You can only write `Outer.Handler` if `Handler` is defined in the object `Outer`, and thus has no reference to the instance of an actual outer object. You're changing the semantics of the OP.

Comment: Erm I'm not really sure what you mean. My point is that I think it's easier to change the structure to create the outer object instead of inferring the outer object. To me it's just more clean. Especially if I can avoid mutable structures.

Comment: Your `Handler` class has no reference to the outer object, therefore, even if it may look cleaner to you, you're changing the semantics intended by the OP. My solution doesn't (and doesn't use mutable structures either).